# How do I stop a function?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So, here is the beginning of the code of a little game. The purpose is to defuse the 3 bombs the closest to 0. I've succeeded in creating the windows, making the countdowns ... But I don't know how to set a button to stop the countdowns. If somebody can help me, it's been days I'm searching for a solution :(

```
import time, os
from Tkinter import *
from math import *
import random

#####################################################
def new():
    fenetre.destroy()
```

> We will focus on that part

```
    def decompte(label, count=10):
        label.config(text="{:.2f}".format(count))
        if count > 0 :
            fen1.after(10,decompte, *(label, count-0.01))

   def stopper():
```

---

```
    fen1=Tk()
    fen1.geometry("500x500")
    lab=Label(fen1, text="")
    lab.pack()
    lab1=Label(fen1, text="")
    lab1.pack()
    lab2=Label(fen1, text="")
    lab2.pack()
    lab3=Label(fen1,text="")
    lab3.place(x=300,y=200)

    x=(random.randint(3,4))
    y=(random.randint(5,6))
    z=(random.randint(6,7))

    decompte(lab, x)
    decompte(lab2, y)
    decompte(lab3,z)

    btn1=Button(fen1, text="stop", command=stopper)
    btn1.pack()
    btn3=Button(fen1, text="quit",command=fen1.destroy)
    btn3.pack()

    lab.place(x=100,y=200)
    lab1.place(x=150,y=200)
    lab2.place(x=200,y=200)

    fen1.mainloop()

######################################################

fenetre= Tk()
fenetre.configure(bg="black")
fenetre.geometry("1024x620")
canvas= Canvas(fenetre, width=1024, height=620,bg="black")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
photo = PhotoImage(file="demineur.gif")
canvas.create_image(512,310, image=photo)
btn= Button(fenetre, text="JOUER",bg="yellow",command=new)
btn.place(x=240,y=500)
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: `if count > 0  and not cancelled:` then just make a global cancelled flag that you set to true when you want to stop

Answer (score 0):

```
countdown = True

def decompte(label, count=10):
    label.config(text="{:.2f}".format(count))
    if count > 0 and countdown: # <- global variable `countdown`
        fen1.after(10,decompte, *(label, count-0.01))

def stopper():
    global countdown
    countdown = False
```